# Why can I not read from the AWS S3 in Spark application anymore?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-spark

I have upgraded to Apache Spark 1.5.1 but I'm not sure if that has caused it. I have my access keys in spark-submit which has always worked.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.<init>(Lorg/jets3t/service/security/AWSCredentials;)V

    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc);
    DataFrame df = sqlContext.read()
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .option("inferSchema", "true")
        .load("s3n://ossem-replication/gdelt_data/event_data/" + args[0]);

    df.write()
        .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
        .save("/user/spark/ossem_data/gdelt/" + args[0]);
```

More of the error below. There is a class that does not contain the method so that means the dependencies are mismatched. It seems like the jets3t does not contain the method RestS3Service.(Lorg/jets3t/service/security/AWSCredentials;)V Can some one explain this to me?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service.<init>(Lorg/jets3t/service/security/AWSCredentials;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.initialize(Jets3tNativeFileSystemStore.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.$Proxy24.initialize(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem.initialize(NativeS3FileSystem.java:272)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2596)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2630)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:296)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:256)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:313)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:35)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:237)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:237)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$take$1.apply(RDD.scala:1277)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.take(RDD.scala:1272)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$first$1.apply(RDD.scala:1312)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.first(RDD.scala:1311)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.firstLine$lzycompute(CsvRelation.scala:101)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.firstLine(CsvRelation.scala:99)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.inferSchema(CsvRelation.scala:82)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvRelation.<init>(CsvRelation.scala:42)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:74)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:39)
    at com.databricks.spark.csv.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:27)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.ResolvedDataSource$.apply(ResolvedDataSource.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:104)
    at com.bah.ossem.spark.GdeltSpark.main(GdeltSpark.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
```

Comment: This sounds like when you upgraded, something changed in the API that made your code invalid. Have you read the changelogs between the version that worked and the version you have now?

Comment: Try reading [this](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/spark-read-data-from-aws-s3-td25260.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem but with Spark 1.6 and I am using Scala instead of Java. The reason for this error is that Spark Core has the Hadoop Client version 2.2 and the Spark cluster installation I was using was 1.6. I had to make the following changes to get it to work.

1. Change the hadoop client dependency to 2.6 (The version of Hadoop I was using)

   ```
   "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.6.0",
   ```
2. Include the hadoop-aws library in my Spark fat jar as this dependency is no longer included in the Hadoop libraries in 1.6

   ```
   "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "2.6.0",
   ```
3. Export the AWS key and secret as environment variables.
4. Specify the following Hadoop configuration in SparkConf

   ```
   val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
   val hadoopConf = sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration
   hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
   hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId", sys.env.getOrElse("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", ""))
   hadoopConf.set("fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey", sys.env.getOrElse("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", ""))
   ```